# Selenium Python: How to set_page_load_timeout, if beyond time return except(not error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I have this code and how to loop if load timeout it will return except and it run next test case

```
def search_action(self, xpath, value):

    try:
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(1)
        element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
        element.send_keys(value)
        element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print('EXCEPT', e)
        pass

    print('success')


se = class_name()


for domain in config['list_domain']:
    se.get_domain(domain)
    for i in range(1, 100):
        xpath = config[domain]['list_test']['search']
        se.search_action(xpath, i)
        se.get_domain(domain)
```

return:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.319
```

I want loop from 1 to 100 i don't want return error

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is not with `set_page_load_timeout`.
You need to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` to wait for element to become clickable.

```py
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

Since you did not share link and xpath details I can't give more detailed answer here.

Comment: i.e. i want to set timeout 10 if it exceeds the time it returns an exception and it runs the next loop

Comment: important i don't want to stop the loop i want to finish it